# parse complex xml attributes with jaxb and make object model

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have an XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<subjectAreaGroup>
    <subjectArea>
        <myObject>
            <layout columnNum="3" />
            <column name="ID" value="101"/>
            <column name="NAME" value="xyz"/>
            <column name="AGE" value="25" />
        </myObject>
    </subjectArea>
</subjectAreaGroup>
```

Here I have to deal with complex attributes and make Object model. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: Can you provide more details in terms of Object model

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson-xml](https://github.com/stanfy/gson-xml). GsonXml is a small library that allows using Google Gson library for XML deserialization. The main idea is to convert a stream of XML pull parser events to a stream of JSON tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your post but i asked to achieve this with Jaxb only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB marshalling which convert the object to xml and vice versa example, convert customer object into a XML file.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}



try {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(100);
        customer.setName("student");
        customer.setAge(29);
    File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();


        // output pretty printed


jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);


    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="100">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>student</name>
</customer>
```

Similarly JAXB marshalling example, convert customer object into a XML file.

```
try {

        File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(customer);

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: I have to parse till column elements and build a List of attributes (ID, NAME, AGE) along with value attributes. I tried your solution but it did not solve the problem.